# Given that $a^a-a^{a-1}=a^x(a-1)$ and a$\neq1$, find the value of $x$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given that
$$a^a-a^{a-1}=a^x(a-1)$$
and $a\neq1$, find the value of $x$.

My approach is to factorise $a^a$ on the LHS and tried to eliminate $(a-1)$ on both sides. This resulted in infinite many values of $x$. Please advise!

Comment: What did you get after factorizing $a^a$ and eliminating $(a-1)$?

Comment: Your approach is good. It's difficult to see why you got stuck.

Comment: Sometimes you will get infinitely many answers! Take an equation like $\sin x=\sqrt{3}/2$ for instance. The answer could be $\pi/3,2\pi/3,7\pi/3,8\pi/3,\dots$ so we would write the answer as $x=\{\pi/3+2n\pi,2\pi/3+2n\pi\},n\in\mathbb{Z}$. The equation has infinitely many solutions. Yours might too!

Answer (score 1):

If
$$a^a-a^{a-1}=a^x(a-1),$$
this means that
$$\color{red}{a^{a-1}}\cdot a-\color{red}{a^{a-1}}\cdot 1=a^x(a-1),$$
this is
$$a^{a-1}(a-1)=a^x(a-1).$$
Now if  $a\ne 1$, then $a-1\ne 0$ and you can divide LHS and RHS by $a-1$:
$$a^{a-1}=a^x,$$
leading to
$$a-1=x.$$
Eliminating $a-1$ on both sides gets to one value for $x$, depending on the value of $a$.